# Apache: Serving assests via HTTP while site is running on HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, http, https, redirect

We have our site running on HTTPS. Is there a way to accept HTTP request for URLs containing `/public/`? For all other HTTP requests they should be redirected to HTTPS.

I have `RoR` application running on `apache` + `passenger`.

**EDIT**

Since the assets `(/public/)` requests will explicitly be on `HTTP`, how about creating another `VHOST` to handle `HTTP` requests. And for any requests other than `/public/` directly could be redirected to `HTTPS`? If we can go this way how can we set this up in `VHOST` for `HTTP`?

**EDIT 2**

I am sorry, I should have been elaborated this in first place. Here is our setup. There two separate applications. One is running on HTTPS (`S`) and other on HTTP (`P`). The app `P` fetches data (a full HTML page, call it `page`) from `S` and render to client. The CSS file used in `page` is located on 'S' so I need to HTTPS in CSS link. I want to use HTTP instead to refer the CSS.

Comment: Your users may get a browser warning about mixed (secure + insecure) content.

Comment: See Edit 2 in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and place a `.htaccess` file with the below contents in your `DocumentRoot`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/public/.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/public/.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

---

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

Listen 80
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin username@somesite.com
DocumentRoot /pathto/DocumentRoot
ServerName domain.com

ErrorLog path/to/your-error_log
CustomLog path/to/your-access_log common

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/public/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin username@somesite.com
DocumentRoot /pathto/DocumentRoot
ServerName domain.com

ErrorLog path/to/your-error_log
CustomLog path/to/your-access_log common

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/public/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#All the other directives pertaining to SSL add below

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try let you know how it goes.

Comment: Since the assets (`/public/`) requests will explicitly be on HTTP, how about creating another `VHOST` for to handle HTTP request. And for any requests other than `/public/` directly could be redirected to HTTPS? If we can go this way how can we set this up in `VHOST` for HTTP?

Comment: Only `domains` can be ascertained through `VirtualHosts` not protocols. from [Name-based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)`Inside each <VirtualHost> block, you will need at minimum a ServerName directive to designate which host is served and a DocumentRoot directive to show where in the filesystem the content for that host lives.` So `VHOST` for HTTP is not a possibility.

Comment: For HTTP we can point the `DocumenRoot` to same location as it's in HTTPS hence both are pointing to same code base. So actually we are able to access the site via both HTTP and HTTPS. Now what we need to do is to redirect all non `/public/` traffic to HTTPS if it comes through HTTP. Does it make sense?

Comment: See Edit 2 in my question above.

Comment: Okay! This is why always give details! Could have saved so much of time!

Comment: Yes, you are right and I apologize again for this. So what's your thought on it?

Comment: @Imran Check the update in answer. Also this is a better solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7810/discussion-between-imran-and-thinkingmonkey)

Comment: Actually, we are having some issue with SSL on Android. That is why I am trying to avoid an HTTPS request and then rewrite it to HTTP. What I want to send an HTTP request directly.

Comment: Oh, I just got you edited answer. Thanks I think this I was looking for.